# Logging all input and output in zsh on demand

Tags: zsh, emacs, logs

Is there any way to activate/deactivate the logging of **all input and output** on a zsh session?

I am using oh-my-zsh with a customized prompt with colors, etc. and I would like to preserve all of these as possible (so that I can later open the log file in Emacs or less and have them re-parse the **ansi color escape codes**)

Does zsh provide any functionality to facilitate this type of logging?

Later on, what would be the best way to visualize the log files in **Emacs** (or some other editor) and have it properly parse all the  **ansi color escape codes**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to use `script`.

`script` is a utility which can create a TTY and then launch a program in that TTY. All output from that TTY can be logged to a file as well. It will log the raw data, including ANSI escapes.
When not given a specific command to execute, it will spawn a new shell. You can use this shell as normal, and then just exit the shell when you're done.

For example

```
script /tmp/mylog
```

And when you're done, just use CTRL+D or `exit` to leave the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Use screen. To quote from the man page:

```
   C-a H       (log)         Begins/ends logging of the current window  to
                             the file "screenlog.n".
```